# Ignore FileNotFoundError - I want to ignore when the ZIP not exist in the folder and jump to the next do the action

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

Ignore FileNotFoundError - I want to ignore when the ZIP not exist in the folder and jump to the next do the action. in case the other files exist, and I want it to do this test to ignore all files that do not exist in the folder and do only those that exist.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CteProc.zip'

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import zipfile
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc.zip')
exemploZip.extractall()
exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc (01).zip')
exemploZip.extractall()
exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc (02).zip')
exemploZip.extractall()
exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc (03).zip')
exemploZip.extractall()
```

Answer (score 0):

use try and except block

```
import warnings
import zipfile
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
try:
    exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc.zip')
    exemploZip.extractall()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass 


try:
    exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc (01).zip')
    exemploZip.extractall()

except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

try:
    exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc (02).zip')
    exemploZip.extractall()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

try:
    exemploZip = zipfile.ZipFile('CteProc (03).zip')
    exemploZip.extractall()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

Comment: Hello codester, it didnt work.    File "c:\Users\PycharmProjects\ExtractAll\main.py", line 8
    except FileNotFoundError: 
    ^^^^^^.    the error keep happening... :(

Comment: @GustavodeCastroFabrini can you show the full traceback error?